# git rebase with changed files per commit in todo

Tags: git

During an interactive rebase, it would be nice if there was an option to provide additional information per commit (preceded by #).  Specifically, files modified for each commit would be helpful.  I couldn't see any solution documented in the git rebase command line arguments, but perhaps there is scripted way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just open another window, `cd` to the repository if needed, and `git show <commit-id>` to see the full commit with diff.  Add `--name-status` to limit the diff to file-name-and-status, for instance.